# How do I do math in a Django inclusion tag with a while loop to show a result based on a filter?

Tags: django

I'm trying to write a simple inclusion tag that will do the following:

1. Get all time recorded for a user ordered by project
2. Add together the time for all projects
3. Return an object list that sorts the projects by most time spent and
   the total

The first item is easy.

```
@register.inclusion_tag('time/_total_time_per_project_ytd.html')
def show_total_time_by_project():
    time = Time.objects.all().order_by('project')
    return {'time': time}
```

I think something like this is what I need:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('time/_total_time_per_project_ytd.html')
def show_total_time_by_project():
    time = Time.objects.all().order_by('project')
    while time.project = project
        # this is where I'm lost. How do I do the math?
        return time_total
    return {'time': time_total}
```

Then I loop through time and the result will be an object_list that has three records with three projects and the total time for each project. As you guessed, I'm a noob, so please use wet noodles. Thanks!

Comment: example: `total += time`

Comment: Can you show us your `Time` model?

Comment: Not really answering your question but all this could and should be done at the database level - SQL databases are not supid bit buckets, they have quite optimized builtin aggregation functions.